# Powershell restore SQL Server database to new database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a database `$CurrentDB` and I want to restore a backup of `$CurrentDB` to `$NewDB`. The T-SQL command looks like this:

```
USE [master]

ALTER DATABASE [NewDB] 
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [NewDB] 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Backups\CurrentDB.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
     MOVE N'CurrentDB' TO N'D:\Databases\NewDB.mdf',  
     MOVE N'CurrentDB_log' TO N'D:\Logs\NewDB_log.ldf',  
     NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5

ALTER DATABASE [NewDB] 
    SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

I am attempting to user `Restore-SqlDatabase` but I don't know how to properly `-RelocateFile`

```
$CurrentDB = "CurrentDB"
$NewDB = "NewDB"
$NewDBmdf = "NewDB.mdf"
$CurrentDBlog = "CurrentDB_log"
$NewDBldf = "NewDB_log.ldf"
$backupfile = $CurrentDB + "ToNewDB.bak"

$RelocateData = New-Object 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($CurrentDB, $NewDBmdf)

$RelocateLog = New-Object 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($CurrentDBlog, $NewDBldf)

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $NewDB -BackupFile 
$backupfile -ReplaceDatabase -NoRecovery -RelocateFile @($RelocateData, 
$RelocateLog)
```

I can't seem to locate an example of what I am attempting to do. I have seen plenty of examples of restoring databases with the same name but different files. I want a different name and different file names. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use SMO just because your're in PowerShell.

```
import-module sqlps

$database = "NewDb"
$backupLocation = "D:\Backups\CurrentDB.bak"
$dataFileLocation = "D:\Databases\NewDB.mdf"
$logFileLocation = "D:\Logs\NewDB_log.ldf"

$sql = @"

USE [master]

ALTER DATABASE [$database] 
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [$database] 
FROM DISK = N'$backupLocation' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
     MOVE N'CurrentDB' TO N'$dataFileLocation',  
     MOVE N'CurrentDB_log' TO N'$logFileLocation',  
     NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5

ALTER DATABASE [$database] 
    SET MULTI_USER
"@

invoke-sqlcmd $sql
```

And if you don't have sqlps installed, you can use System.Data.SqlClient from Powershell to run TSQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
$RelocateData = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile]::new($CurrentDB, $NewDBmdf)
$RelocateLog = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile]::new($CurrentDBlog, $NewDBldf)

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $NewDB -BackupFile $backupfile `
-ReplaceDatabase -NoRecovery -RelocateFile @($RelocateData, $RelocateLog)
```